# Validating count of tokens in expression

Tags: c#, math

I am writing a C# program which do some filtering expression in the following format( Conditions joined by binary operations AND and OR)

```
Name==Me && Age>18 || City== NewYork
```

There is a tokenizer which does

```
 {Name, ==, Me , &&, Age, >, 18, ||, City, ==, NewYork}.
```

After that filtering logic will create a filter.

Problem: I would like to do a first level validation on the number of tokens at the tokenizer. But I cannot figure out the what is the number of tokens.

```
if(!IsValidCount(tokens.Count)) return false;
```

What will be the logic inside IsValidCount()?

This is probably more maths than C#, any help is appreciated

Comment: What does `tokens.Count` return? For my understanding it should be `11`, shouldn´t it?

Comment: is tokenizer `string` written with curly braces like shown in example?

Comment: The number of tokens in the filter . For Name==Me && Age>18 || City== NewYork, 11 is the count

Comment: And what exactly can´t you figure out? We don´t know what your `IsValidCount`-method does and why or why not it returns `false`.

Comment: @Nino . No. it is just tokens

Comment: so, tokens is list of strings?

Comment: But how do you store the tokens into a collection? In particular: show how `tokens` is declared.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That is not really related to my problem in hand. I am only after if the number of token are correct.

Comment: Well, what does your validate-method look like? How should it consider `11` to be valid or not? Your question is unclear as long as you are not any more specific on what you´re actually doing and what you have so far.

Comment: @HimBromBeere In your first comment you are right. It is 11.It has 6 operators three conditions and two binary operators. My issue is to create a IsValidCount() for any number of tokens

Comment: If your question goes about how validate should be implemented I guess no-one here can answer this as we don´t know which oprators you use, the datatypes of the operands and much more. What about unary operators? Do they exist in your world? What about datatype bool? Whould this be valid: `Name=Me && BoolParam && ...`?

Comment: every condition operator will have two operands(Name==John) and this conditions can be joined by Binary AND and OR

Comment: Well, then it's just `(count % 4) == 3`

Comment: @BurnsBA. Yep, you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each condition must contain 3 tokens (2 fields + 1 comparator). 
In addition, for each additional condition, we must add a binary operation (AND/OR) to separate them (making it a total of 4 tokens).

As a result, a valid tokenizer will consist of the following number of tokens:

3 + 4 + 4 + 4 ...

Therefore, you can verify if the number of tokens is valid with this formula:

```
string tokenizer = "{Name, ==, Me , &&, Age, >, 18, ||, City, ==, NewYork}";
var tokens = tokenizer.Split(',');
if (tokens.Length % 4 == 3)
{
    //valid
}
else
{
    //not valid
}
```

You could get more strict and check that every fourth token is indeed a binary operation, but that is for you to decide. I hope I was helpful

Comment: Yes, FYI, BurnsBA actually answered this in the comment a bit quicker than you.

Comment: @Jimmy well, I was writing my answer and didn't get to refresh the page so I didn't see it

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this problem. I'm guessing this could be written a bit cleaner and easier to understand, but... :)
Also, it may not work correct in all the cases, but you should get the idea. I have also added few examples.

Ok, here is the code with comments. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "{ Name, ==, Me, &&, Age, >, 18, ||, City, ==, NewYork }";
    bool ok1 = IsValidExpression(s);
    s = "{ Name, ==, Me, &&, Age, >, 18 }";
    bool ok2 = IsValidExpression(s);
    s = "{ Name, ==, ==, Me, &&, Age, >, 18 }";
    bool notok = IsValidExpression(s);
    s = "{ Name, Me, &&, Age, >, 18 }";
    bool notok2 = IsValidExpression(s);
    s = "{ Name, ==, Me, &&, Age, > ||, City, ==, NewYork }";
    bool notok3 = IsValidExpression(s);
    Console.ReadLine();

}

static bool IsValidExpression(string stringToValidate)
{
    List<string> tokens = stringToValidate.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Split(',').Select(t => t = t.Trim()).ToList();

    List<string> operators = new List<string>() { "==", "!=", "<", ">" };
    List<string> boolOps = new List<string>() { "&&", "||" };
    //split by and/or
    var boolOpsIndexes = tokens.Where(t => boolOps.Contains(t)).Select(t => tokens.IndexOf(t)).ToList();
    //check for AND/OR positions
    if (boolOpsIndexes.Any(b => b == 0) || boolOpsIndexes.Any(b => b == tokens.Count - 1)) //bool op is at first or last position
        return false;

    //make "virtual one at the end, so the program enters loop one or more times
    boolOpsIndexes.Add(tokens.Count - 1);

    int lastOpIndex = 0;
    //iterate through all indexes where and/or were found
    foreach (var boolOpIndex in boolOpsIndexes)
    {
        //take expressions from last AND/OR to next one
        var tokensPart = tokens.Skip(lastOpIndex).Take(boolOpIndex).ToList();

        if (tokensPart.Count != 3) //there is not 3 parts there... not ok
            return false;

        //if there is more or less than one comparison operator
       if (tokensPart.Count(t => operators.Contains(t)) != 1)
            return false; //not ok

        //check for both sides of operators
        int opIndex = tokensPart.Where(t => operators.Contains(t)).Select(t => tokensPart.IndexOf(t)).First();
        //check for operators positions
        if (opIndex == 0 || opIndex == tokensPart.Count - 1) //operator is at first or last position
            return false; //not ok

        //check if left and right side od operator contains something and not operator
        if (tokensPart[opIndex - 1] != string.Empty && !operators.Contains(tokensPart[opIndex - 1])
            &&
            tokensPart[opIndex + 1] != string.Empty && !operators.Contains(tokensPart[opIndex + 1]))
            continue;

        lastOpIndex = boolOpIndex + 1;
    }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: My issue is how can you validate the count?

Comment: you're unclear of what you want to check for? This example that i wrote will tell you that there are three operators. What else you want? Do you want to test if every operator has two values to compare and that they are on the left and right side of operator?

Comment: also, which are possible operators? `{ "==", "!=", "<", ">" }`? Anything else? And about bool operators - are there `&&`, `||` or `^`...?

Comment: @Jimmy Ok, now i get it... I have edited my code, so take a look at this example.

Comment: Thanks, but it is easier than that. Check Innat3 Answer

Comment: @jimmy, no problem. I was trying to catch all scenarios. His solution will  pronounce valid expressions such as `"{ Name, ==, Me }` as invalid, and allow wrong order of params `"{ Name, ==, Me, &&, Age, >, 18, ||, ==, City, NewYork }"`

Comment: @jimmy, no problem. I was trying to catch all scenarios. His solution will  pronounce valid expressions such as `"{ Name, ==, Me }` as invalid, and allow wrong order of params `"{ Name, ==, Me, &&, Age, >, 18, ||, ==, City, NewYork }"`

Answer (score 0):

I think [MathParser-org-mXparser](http://mathparser.org/) can easily help - you can calculate expression but also play with the expression tokens.

```
Expression e = new Expression("Name==Me && Age>18 || City== NewYork");
mXparser.consolePrintTokens(e.getCopyOfInitialTokens());
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  --------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] | Expression tokens: |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |    TokenIdx |       Token |        KeyW |     TokenId | TokenTypeId |  TokenLevel |  TokenValue |   LooksLike |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           0 |        Name |             |          -1 |          -1 |           0 |         NaN |    argument |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           1 |          == |          == |           1 |           3 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           2 |          Me |             |          -1 |          -1 |           0 |         NaN |    argument |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           3 |          && |          && |           1 |           2 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           4 |         Age |             |          -1 |          -1 |           0 |         NaN |    argument |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           5 |           > |           > |           4 |           3 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           6 |          18 |       _num_ |           1 |           0 |           0 |          18 |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           7 |          || |          || |           3 |           2 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           8 |        City |             |          -1 |          -1 |           0 |         NaN |    argument |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           9 |          == |          == |           1 |           3 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          10 |     NewYork |             |          -1 |          -1 |           0 |         NaN |    argument |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please follow [mXparser tutorial](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/).

Regards